# Wordpress Help on post

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm having a bit of a problem I have created a post and it shows on my [blog](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/ryan/blog) but as soon as you click on the title link it says "Sorry, no posts were found." and even in the [homepage](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/ryan/) where the recent post doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a permalink issue. If you turned on "pretty" urls, make sure you've created the appropriate .htaccess file. Once you edit your permalink structure, WP  will generate the contents you need to put inside your htaccess file. Copy the contents, paste inside a file, save it as .htaccess and upload to your blog root folder.

Comment: You should also make sure the .htaccess file is writeable as well by using something along the lines of `chmod 777 .htaccess` or `chown apache:apache .htaccess`.

Comment: thanks it worked, now is there any possibilities to hide one the thing in sidebar when you get into the blog part?

Comment: Yeah, make a new question though please and I or someone else will answer, that way other people can benefit from the answer to the problem should they run into it :)